# Where can we publish our poetry preprints?

Tags: poetry

I have some poems and want to share them on the internet, and am checking if there are some repositories like what we have for scholarly works (for example, arXiv is for mathematical preprints).
I mean a site where poets upload their own works there.

Comment: What do you mean by "preprint"? Are you planning to publish it elsewhere too?

Comment: maybe yes maybe no.